# CSS HTML5 table <td> override by <tr>

Tags: css, html

I have a table and I have set to **td** to this css:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

but I need to override background color of single **tr** row by another color.

Is this possible? It isn't working if I will not remove  this  style above.

Thank you

Comment: Identify that single TR somehow (using `class` or `id`) then add the appropriate style that overrides the above.

Comment: Use `!important` for that `tr`

Comment: you can use `#f9f9f9 !important`

Comment: this isn't working, It works only when I remove TD style- in code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the tr style before the td class will give it the correct specificity.

Alternatively giving the tr a class will increase it's specificity and an id even more so.

Lastly using important will give maximum specificity and overide all styles.

```css
.table-striped>tbody>tr {
    background-color: #b00;
}
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, 
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td>row 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Nth Child:**

I just realised that ***"I think"*** you are trying to do odd even colours for your cells rows. If this is the case you should do this instead.

```css
.table-striped tr {
    background-color: #b00;
}
.table-striped td:nth-child(odd), 
.table-striped th:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**[CHECK YOUR SPECIFICITY](http://specificity.keegan.st/)**

There is an online checker here which will tell you what styles will win in a fight. Bear in correct order is the best way to create specificity.

---

**EDITS**

As per your request:

The overwriting styles should still be applied to the td but using the rows class. if you want the yellow to be alternating simply move `.table-striped .Yellow td` above the overwriting `odd style`.

```css
.table-striped tr {
    background-color: #b00;
}
.table-striped td:nth-child(odd), 
.table-striped th:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.table-striped .Yellow td{
    background-color: #ba0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-striped" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="Yellow">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have something like you - striped table, but I want use one class and override this grey/red color. Only one line. For exapmle I will add to one TR class="yellow" and all rows will be grey/red and only this one will be yellow

Comment: I want something like here: https://jsfiddle.net/Desttro/hxLj7bkx/ that only one line with class "color" will be all in yellow

Answer (score 0):

In general, I doubt if your selectors need to be as specific as they are. The less specific they are, the easier they are to maintain.

What you're probably looking for something along these lines:

```
.table-striped tr:nth-child(odd) td {}

.table-striped tr.override-class:nth-child(odd) td {}
```